# What causes a L3 cache miss in CPU?

Tags: caching, memory, profiling, cpu, opencl

I have a question regarding the relation between cache misses of difference cache levels in a x86 architecture (Say Xeon X5660).

I did some profiling over an OpenCL application (Blackscholes), on some performance counters. For each counter, I sum up all the values over all cores and get this result:

```
 instructions #: 493167746502.000000 

 L3_MISS #: 1967809.000000 

 L1_MISS  #: 2344383795.000000 

 L2_DATA_MISS #: 901131.000000 

 L2_MISS #: 1397931.000000 

 memory loads #: 151559373227.000000
```

The question is why the number of L3 misses is bigger than the number of L2 misses? (I keep rerunning the profiling many times and the variance is not significant). What I thought basically is:

L2 misses = L3 hits + L3 misses

Could someone explain me what goes wrong here, did I miss something?

Putting it a bit further, what causes a cache read for the last level cache (CPU) of CPU? Is it just simply a data miss from L2?

Thanks

Comment: Could it be that you are measuring this on an architecture with separate L2 caches and a unified L3?  If so, you might just be reading cache misses from one L2, and the L3 numbers might be from a unified L3.

Comment: Yes, I noticed about this. But I'm sure that I have summed up for all the cores. So it shouldn't matter whether it is unified or not, right?

Comment: Another thing is, when I do this: "cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cache/index2/type", what I got is "unified". It is known that L2 cache is private and 256K per core for all westmere architectures, isn't it?

Comment: If you look at the manual for Westmere, (here: http://download.intel.com/products/processor/manual/325462.pdf). Section 18.6.2 says that L3 cache performance events are maintained in one spot in the "uncore" of the processor.  I suspect that when you query these counters from a particular core, it is passing that query down to the uncore and returning the count for the L3.  It's not keeping track of the cores that initiated memory accesses that caused L3 misses.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image: The 32 nanometer, six core Westmere-EP chip]

Image Ref : http://www.theregister.co.uk/2010/02/03/intel_westmere_ep_preview/

As you can see above, In 'Westmere-EP' architecture block of 3 cores share a section of L3 cache. So what "boiler96" says makes sense.
You are either getting L2 misses for individual core or your L3 miss count is coming from Uncore which is combined miss count of misses from all cores.